# Can we render InputStream from Spring Boot Backend on React Frontend?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, rest, inputstream

I have a virtual file system in my java spring boot backend that converts any file into an InputStream, I am sending this InputStream using REST to my React frontend. Is there anyway I can accordingly render this InputStream on the frontend?

This InputStream may be an text file, image file, xml file, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. I've an example using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

```
  const readFile = async (filename: string) => {
    try {
      // fetch your file
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/file/${filename}`, {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
      });

      // read your response into a blob
      const file = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: "text/plain",
      });

      // read your blob as text
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        alert(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    } catch (e) {

      // error handling
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
```

If you have an image you would want to use `URL.createObjectURL`:

```
      const file = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: "image/png",
      });
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
```

Comment: Thank you! Similarly, is there a way for me to retrieve an image if the response was an InputStream of an image?

Comment: If you find this answer helpful I'd appreciate it being marked as an accepted answer.